# Implementing a glowing effect on 3D objects with Direct3D 11

Tags: c++, rendering, directx11, hlsl, graphic-effects

I'm interested in implementing a glowing effect on some 3D objects. More specifically, I want to make a star that has a sort of halo around it, as it can be seen in the photo:

[image]

I've seen on [Rastertek](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut46.html) the 2D implementation, but I have no idea how it could be done in 3D. I've also read about HDR and bloom effects, but I'm not sure if those would apply here. What Direct3D 11 techniques should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the geometry shader to extrude faces from the sphere to face the camera and then use a pixel shader to create a nice glow, this is how I've done it in the past, I'm going to copypaste most of my answer from an earlier question about glow shader and go on a dig for my old shader files.

**Geometry Shaders**

A geometry shader is a part of the graphics pipeline similar to the pixel(fragment) & vertex-shaders. Unlike those two though the geometry shader operates once on each primitive, a primitive being triangles lines or points.

The geometry shader doesn't just use primitives as input it can also output up to a defined max of new primitives, this is the true power of a geomotry shader, it can be used to cull primitives and/or expand them.

**Edge Detection**

I said earlier that the geometry shader works on primitives such as triangles lines or points, this was not a definite list and there is one primitive that is of particular intrest to us:

The Triangle adjecant

[image: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205124(v=vs.85).aspx]

The triangle adjecant provides not only data for the triangle but for all neighbouring triangles. If the main triangle faces the camera and an adjecant triangle does not then the triangle lies on the edge and we can proceed.

To check if a triangle is backfacing calculate it's normal and dot product it with the cameras normal. I'll leave the details of the calculation as an exercise to the reader, it's not hard.

**Face Extrusion**

Now we come to the tricky part, start by drawing a line from the camera to an arbitrary point on the edge and use the cross product of this line and the edge to get the direction of where to extrude the new face, we'll call this *e*, make sure to normalize it.

Create two new points *x* distance from the edge points in the direction of *e*, *x* here being a glow amount. From these two new points and the edge we can output a new face in the geometry shader and create a glow around the object.

**But wait!**

This will only work if the edge is completly straight or concave*, if the edge is convex we'll have a gap.

[image]

To solve this first project the edge point normals on the vector *e* this creates two new vectors *n1* and *n2*, make sure to normalize these too.

Like before create two new points *x* distance from the edge points in the direction of *n1* and *n2* and create new faces from these points, this will create a more robust glow.

[image]

**Pixel Shader**

I'll leave creation of the pixelshader as an excercise to the reader for now.